# Unable to restart mysql after changing the datadir

Tags: mysql, database, windows, datadirectory

I am unable to restart the server after changing the default `datadir` from `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data` to `D:/Data`.

- I changed `datadir` to `datadir="D:/Data"`
- Then I stopped `mysql`
- Copied the `Data` directory to `D:/`
- Attempted to restart the server
- Unable to start

What could be the reason for it?

Error snapshot:

[image]

However, it works fine if the original datadir path is restored.

Comment: Did you check the event log, as that is where all service errors end up? Most likely the MySQL service account does not have permission to the folder, and thus cannot open its metadatabases, causing startup to fail miserably.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Event log shows mysql error but doesn't show any error message or code. What could be done to give permission to that folder? I already have permission to read and write to that folder.

Comment: @SuhailGupta In which file/files you changed the `datadir="D:/Data"`

Comment: @SuhailGupta according to your screenshot MySQL is running as a network service. That's the one that should have permissions, not you.

Comment: @dbw my.ini inside c:/programdata ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assign full permissions to the `NETWORK SERVICE` for `D:/Data`

Comment: like a charm! :)

Comment: After so much searching this answer helped finally, Everyone was saying give appropriate permission.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure `my.ini` is ANSI encoded with a tool like Notepad++.

I updated the `datadir` in `my.ini` with Windows Notepad and it apparently converted it to UTF-8; I copied the file over to a system with Notepad++, converted it back to ANSI before copying it back to the MySQL server and was able to start the MySQL service successfully.

Comment: this was my problem and this fixed it.  kinda strange this would affect reading of the file for starting the server